# How to +1 month on datetime in phpmysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data

```
table(id, name, date_create)
table(1, 'Iphone 4S', '2012-06-18 17:19:05') // format Y-m-d H:i:s
```

And phpmysql

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date_create BETWEEN('date_create' AND '2012-07-18 17:19:05') // date_create +1 month
```

How to +1 month in this query

Comment: use mysql DATE_ADD() function

Comment: A simple search on Google will get you all you need : [Date Functions (MySQL Documentation)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
WHERE date_create BETWEEN(DATE_ADD(date_create, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND '2012-07-18 17:19:05')
```

Answer (score 3):

use `DATE_ADD`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(date_create) BETWEEN DATE(date_create) AND 
                                DATE(DATE_ADD(date_create,INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```